# Calculated Sharepoint Dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I have 3 potential columns that are due dates in a Sharepoint online/365 List.
-Bid Due Date
-Customer Specified Due Date
-Proposal Due Date

They are written in order of importance above and only one of them will be filled and the others are "blank." I put together an if/then statement that *should* pull only the column that has a date in it (if for some reason there are multiple columns with dates, it still should only pull the most important one with a date in it).

I have tried everything and can not get the dates to calculate properly. It may calculate properly for one but I get "null" results for everything else. I've searched around and found that the "blank" columns are actually not blank but have a hidden default value. I've tested with an if blank statement and confirm they are not coming up as blank, but I still can't get ANY FORMULA to work and calculate any value.

PLEASE HELP. Just looking to pull whatever the most important column is with a date in it, into a new calculated column.

Comment: Bro, what do you need exactly yo calculate in the calculation field?!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula to get the non-blank value form these columns

```
IF([Bid Due Date]="",IF([Customer Specified Due Date]="",IF([Proposal Due Date]="","",[Proposal Due Date]),[Customer Specified Due Date]) ,[Bid Due Date])
```